# Conditional Index Route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am looking for a solution to change the index route of React Router based on some condition:

If a specific attribute (e.g. "externalAPIConnected") of a User object is true, index route should be "search" and if false, index route should be "settings" (to take some action so attribute changes to true).

Currently, I use the following workaround:

App.js

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Dashboard />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    loader: credentialsLoader,
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <Navigate to="/settings" state={true} />
      },
    ...
  }
```

SettingsPage.jsx (settings route)

```
export default function SettingsPage() {
  const credentials = useCredentials();
  const location = useLocation();
  const isRedirect = location.state;
  
  if (isRedirect && credetials.user.externalAPIConnected) {
      return <Navigate to="/search" />
  } else {
      return (
        // page content
      );
  }
```

However, I was wondering if there is a more "elegant" solution that doesn't redirect twice?

Comment: Are you basically just wanting the `"/"` route to conditionally redirect to either of `"/settings"` or `"/search"` as a "default route" based on the `credetials.user.externalAPIConnected` value from the `useCredentials` hook?

Comment: I think that’s it @DrewReese

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are basically just wanting the "/" route to conditionally redirect to either of "/settings" or "/search" as a "default route" based on the `credentials.user.externalAPIConnected` value from the `useCredentials` hook then I'd suggest a simple root component that does just that.

Instead of *unconditionally* redirecting from `"/"` to `"/settings"` and then *conditionally* redirecting to `"/search"` create a component that *conditionally* redirects from `'/"` to either of the target default routes.

Example:

```
const DashboardIndex = () => {
  const { user } = useCredentials();

  return (
    <Navigate
      to={user.externalAPIConnected ? "/search" : "/settings"}
      replace
    />
  );
};
```

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Dashboard />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    loader: credentialsLoader,
    children: [
      { index: true, element: <DashboardIndex /> },
      { path: "search", element: <SearchPage /> },
      { path: "settings", element: <SettingsPage /> },
      ...
    ],
  },
  ...
]);
```